For Code optimization ,here is any way to avoid multiple OR(||) statement to a single line of code
For the level of code optimization there is any way to reduce multiple line of OR(||) statement to a single line, means with easy readable format
if (Convert.ToByte(hfStatus.Value) == 4 || Convert.ToByte(hfStatus.Value) == 5 || Convert.ToByte(hfStatus.Value) == 12 || Convert.ToByte(hfStatus.Value) == 11 ||Convert.ToByte(hfStatus.Value) == 3 || Convert.ToByte(hfStatus.Value) == 8 || Convert.ToByte(hfStatus.Value) == 10 || Convert.ToByte(hfStatus.Value) == 9)
{
//contents
}


Take a step back. Why is hfStatus.Value not already comparable to these numbers? Why does it need to be converted to byte? We don't know anything about the context here but the obvious is to either extract the conversion to byte or avoid it altogether. And BTW, the best code is usually the most readable. Counting lines of code is rarely the right approach to optimising these days.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever , hfstatus.value default store sting value, i need to be a byte value, it is fetched data storing  from the DB. i got the answer which i required from the answers.

It's not really clear what you want to optimize here. The code abocve literally consists of a single line, so what exactly do you want here?

Note that optimizing for readability and performance are two different, and often opposing goals. If you optimize for performance you need to do benchmarks to evaluate any changes, see benchmark .net.

C# 9 introduced new type of pattern matching, which might make the code a bit more clearly arranged:
byte hfState = Convert.ToByte(hfStatus.Value);
if(hfstate is 4 or 5 or 12 or 11 or 3 or 8 or 10 or 9)
{
   // do something
}

Another recommendation is to use constants to make your code even more readable:
const byte connectionTooSlow = 4;
const byte serverNotFound = 5;
if(hfState is connectionTooSlow or serverNotFound or ...)
{
}


There's no good reason for that to be a single line.
var statusByte = Convert.ToByte(hfStatus.Value);
if (
    statusByte == 3 || 
    statusByte == 4 || 
    statusByte == 5 || 
    statusByte == 8 || 
    statusByte == 9 ||
    statusByte == 10 || 
    statusByte == 11 || 
    statusByte == 12
) {
    // ...
}

will do the conversion once, and it's clearer to see what's going on.
You could also add comments for the different magic number cases now:
if (
    statusByte == 3 ||  // Bad descriptor
    statusByte == 4 ||  // Color too orange
...


Instead of adding comments, it would be better to use well-named constants (or enum values).

You can use HashSet for it . HashSet is particularly efficient for checking membership because it provides O(1) average-time complexity for lookups.
HashSet<byte> validValues = new HashSet<byte> { 4, 5, 12, 11, 3 };
if (validValues.Contains(Convert.ToByte(hfStatus.Value)))
{
    // Your code here
}

The other options can be using switch statement or using Array or List

I'm not sure a HashSet is a great idea at all for a small known set of byte-sized integers.

You can also use , Array or List

I have also suggested different ways

HashSet  is not a good idea at all for a set of small numbers like this one

Arrays and Lists do not have O(1) lookup complexity.

you can always do allocaiton-free stackalloc[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }.Contains(toTest) and it will behave like a real or, reaturning early. Or is N complexity anyway

I tried a few different methods (Benchmark results) and, in order from best to worst we have: static comparison (SomeBody's pattern matching answer) at 0.0457ns, stackalloc with Contains (Ivan) at 2.88ns, a cached version of your hashset Contains at 3.27ns, a for loop of an array at 5.92ns, List.Contains at 17.3ns, LINQ .Any of an array at 37.6ns, and your HashSet Contains (building the hashset immediately before checking) at 77.2ns. It's about 1700 times slower than pattern matching, and 13 times slower than a humble for loop.

You can find my benchmark code here: https://pastebin.com/XrRLKfrf but the takeaway is that everything has it's place, and building a hashset isn't free.
